# Wordpress || Disable Auto Popup from Popup Maker When Form is Submitted or Closed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**Thank you for reading this question !!**

1. Actually I am using Popup Maker Plugin to Make a Popup on every page
   of my website.
2. Inside that popup I had added one form.
3. For form, I am using Contact Form 7 plugin.
4. But the main challenge is that, how can I make that popup disabled
   in all page when someone close the popup or submit that form.
5. If you want more detail please comment.

**It is a kind request, Please Don't Spoil this Question or forum if you don't know the answer.**

Comment: https://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/140-conditions This is a configuration question, not a coding question, so it's very likely off topic for SO.